# Ingress configuration setup doesn't redirect to correct page

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

Need help on setting up the ingress in K8S. Thank you in advance.

I have configured, NGINX Controller and Cert-Manager on the AKS cluster using Helm.

Here is the svc, pods list.
[image]

Next - deployed two pods, and respected services here are those names and can be found in the above-attached image.

- pod/rpe-delivers-orders-dcs-api*
- service/rpe-delivers-orders-dcs-api
- pod/rpe-delivers-orders-proxy-api*
- service/rpe-delivers-orders-proxy-api

Next - when I try to set up the ingress like below for the above two services.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rpe-delivers-orders-dcs-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: dcs-cluster-issuer
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - raag.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: dcs-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: raag.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /orders-dcs(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rpe-delivers-orders-dcs-api
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /orders-proxy(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rpe-delivers-orders-proxy-api
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rpe-delivers-orders-dcs-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

- Working as expected - raag.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com
- Working as expected - raag.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/rpe-delivers-orders-dcs-api
- **Not working** - raag.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/rpe-delivers-orders-proxy-api

My goal is for the below URLs should redirect to two different web pages:

- raag.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/rpe-delivers-orders-dcs-api
- raag.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/rpe-delivers-orders-proxy-api

Please let me know if I'm missing any information or didn't do the setup right.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the block of `rpe-delivers-orders-proxy-api` in your ingress config

```
- path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rpe-delivers-orders-proxy-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

If you have any path rewrite option and requirement in that case you can create the two different ingress

**No 1.** **rewrite** **ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name:  ingress-first
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: dcs-cluster-issuer
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - raag.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: dcs-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: raag.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /orders-dcs(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rpe-delivers-orders-dcs-api
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /orders-proxy(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rpe-delivers-orders-proxy-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

**No 2.** simple ingress which will be also there as per your requirement

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-second
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - raag.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: dcs-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: raag.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: rpe-delivers-orders-proxy-api
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: rpe-delivers-orders-dcs-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

**Update** :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-second
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - raag.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: dcs-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: raag.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /orders-proxy
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rpe-delivers-orders-proxy-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: check the Nginx ingress container logs to debug when you are hitting the path request.

Comment: Hi Harsh - I tried both the way, but it is still the same. 

Here is my new setup as per suggestion.
kubectl apply -f .\rpe-delivers-orders-ingress.yaml --namespace dcs-ingress-nginx
kubectl apply -f .\rpe-delivers-orders-basic-ingress.yaml --namespace dcs-ingress-nginx

Comment: Try removing the regrex,updated in answer, also check the logs of nginx controller any issue there ?

Comment: i have updated the second ingress please check once and also check the logs of nginx ingress pod.

Comment: Checking the log for Nginx now. Thank you.

Comment: I confirmed the service names are correct in the basic ingress file and also removed the regex from annotations. But it is still the same Harsh. Thank you.

Comment: hope you have tried with deleting the old ingress and only above ingress are running, what's on log ? status code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235491/discussion-between-anuraag-vodnala-and-harsh-manvar).